# Assign to console app an icon (program code) in VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, icons, executable

Hi guys :)
I have my console app finished (c++).
And now I'm looking for a way to give it an icon. So when I distribute it, it keeps the icon.
I didn't find anything yet. I would really appreciate some help!

**Nobody want to continue helping me? :(**

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519844/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-a-console-app-in-visual-studio

Comment: Sorry it doen't work like there. This VS is newer and its C#, I'm on c++

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the same in VS 2005 as VS 2008, but C++ is different from C#. I'm not in front of a computer to look. Details in your question are very important.

Comment: You are right. I missed to write it down. I edited it.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a resource file (.rc) and specify an icon to get it included in the binary. The first icon (the one with the lowest ID number) will be the icon of your application.

Unfortunately the new express editions do not come with an integrated resource editor anymore, but you can use the excellent free alternative [ResEd](http://radasm.cherrytree.at/resed/) for this task.

You simply have to create a new .rc file, add the icon and then include the .rc file in your c++ project.

Comment: I have the full VS2005. I have a *.rc file now. And now?

Comment: I also get this error on compiling: `1>------ Build started: Project: GenericCommandConverter, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling resources...
1>.\GenericCommandConverter3.rc(31) : error RC2176 : old DIB in DocumentApplications.ico; pass it through SDKPAINT
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Documents and Settings\...\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>GenericCommandConverter - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========`

Comment: Where do I have to include it? Autocompletion doen't offer it?

Comment: If you have the full version you should be able to add the icon directly to the project and let visual studio create the rc file for you. There's some info about the specific error in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3384112/564265