# Can't open resource editor in VC++ 2008

Tags: visual-c++, resources

Whenever I tried to open rc file in VC++ 2008, I get this error message.

[image]

The message said the file is corrupted, but I know the error message is not correct since I can open the resource file in another machine without any problem. I can't even open rc file from a project just created. I didn't have this problem before. I think this somehow is related to installation of VC++ 2010 Express. But that's just a guess. I tried several suggestions over google in vain.

Any idea how I can resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After following a series of suggestions for several hours from a wrong answerer, I found [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/e4ef7904-0947-4792-aa4a-b28077146d02/) and Andy Larter's answer solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

VC++ Express doesn't include or support a resource editor. If you've installed VC++ Express after VC++ 2008 then it's highly likely it broke something. I'd try uninstalling VC++ Express.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you provide with any reference for what you are claiming? Actually, that was my suspicion too but couldn't find any document supporting it.

Comment: Unfortunately no, however it is something I have experienced.

Comment: Just uninstalled VC++ 2010, but the resource editor does not work yet.

Comment: When I experienced this issue I had to reinstall VC++.

Comment: Well, I appreciate your time to answer my question. But you'd better answer with more care and in detail. It takes a lot of time to uninstall/reinstall software packages. You made suggestion to uninstall VC++ 2010 so I followed and it didn't work. You are now telling me to reinstall VC++ 2008. Is "reinstalling" repairing or deleting & installing VS 2008? The small things will make difference.

Comment: Your answer was simply wrong. For that, -1. Reinstalling looked like a solution but wasn't. I finally get an answer from MS forum. Please read my update.